# Roblox script does not run

Tags: roblox

I need help with my code. I'm trying to make a button give you a sword but the script will detect clicks but will not run. It keeps saying that the script detected a click but it does nothing and ends.

```
function Click(mouse)
    for tool in ipairs(player.Backpack:GetChildren()) do
        tool:Destroy()
        print("Tool destroyed.")
    end
    for tool in ipairs(player.StarterPack:GetChildren()) do
        tool:Destroy()
        print("Tool destroyed.")
    end
    local cloneb = game.ServerStorage.Darkheart:Clone()
    cloneb.Parent = player.backpack
    print("Tool moved.")
    local clones = game.ServerStorage.Darkheart:Clone()
    clones.Parent = player.StarterPack
    print("Tool moved.")
end

script.Parent.MouseButton1Down:Connect(Click)

wait ()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and largest problem, you have an extra end after the print("tool moved") message.  Here is the corrected script.

```
Mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()

for tool in ipairs(player.Backpack:GetChildren()) do
    tool:Destroy()
    print("Tool destroyed.")
end
for tool in ipairs(player.StarterPack:GetChildren()) do
    tool:Destroy()
    print("Tool destroyed.")
end
local cloneb = game.ServerStorage.Darkheart:Clone()
cloneb.Parent = player.backpack
print("Tool moved.")
local clones = game.ServerStorage.Darkheart:Clone()
clones.Parent = player.StarterPack
print("Tool moved.")


wait ()
end
```

edit:

```
Mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function()

for tool in ipairs(player.Backpack:GetChildren()) do
    tool:Destroy()
    print("Tool destroyed.")
end
for tool in ipairs(player.StarterPack:GetChildren()) do
    tool:Destroy()
    print("Tool destroyed.")
end
local cloneb = game.ServerStorage.Darkheart:Clone()
cloneb.Parent = player.backpack
print("Tool moved.")
local clones = game.ServerStorage.Darkheart:Clone()
clones.Parent = player.StarterPack
print("Tool moved.")


wait ()
end) -- added a parenthesis / )
```

Try this one.  I'm not entirely sure if it will work because I cannot test it with your file, and if it doesn't here is a resource to look at:  https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/event/Mouse/Button1Down

Comment: It says it is missing a ) . I added it at the end and it didn't work.

Comment: It dosen't. I did something else, but this would probably normally work.

Comment: Now, weeks later, it turned out that it was that player was not defined.